# Javascript lib / jQuery plugin to interact with SOAP

Tags: jquery, soap, javascript

1. Do you know of a good Javascript library to interact with SOAP?
2. Do you know of a good jQuery plugin to interact with SOAP?

This is for a production server, so i am looking for something which is tested and works good, among different browsers.

thanks in advance

best regards,

Fernando Gabrieli

Answer (score 3):

there is a relatively new plugin available:

http://plugins.jquery.com/soap/

I forked the project, and have been working on some modifications (the plugin did not handle the service I was working with). I hope to get my updates merged at some point, but would be happy to have any feedback.

https://github.com/zachofalltrades/jquery.soap

Comment: update: my updates were merged into the original project (two years ago) and that project continues to get periodic updates -- so you should look at https://github.com/doedje/jquery.soap if you want to use SOAP via jQuery

Answer (score 0):

There unfortunately is really not a lot available in that space: the only one I've seen in the past is http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqSOAPClient, and it has not been updated for some time.

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Thank you Femi and Nathan. We'll go with a different approach based on the fact there aren't many references on these libraries or plugins.

We will go with JSON instead, for implementing the services. Javascript on client side and PHP with JSON output server side.

Comment: JSON is probably a superior option from the browser perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I used [apache cxf](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CXF20DOC/JavaScript+Clients) to generate javascript libraries specifically to call cxf annotated web services at one point.  That might be a possibility.

Not sure how you are planning on deploying this but keep the cross domain browser limitations in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I think the correct answer is: don't do it.  Instead, create a server side REST API that talks to your SOAP service and translates it to JSON.  Then the client side is a joke.